# Display alert no matter which part of the div i tap on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("#test").on('click',  begin);

function begin(){
  var test = ["apple","pear","banan"];
  for (var i=0; i < test.length; i++){
    console.log(test[i]);
    var listItem = document.createElement('text'),
    html = `<pstyle='margin-left:12%;padding-             top:8%;color:white;font-family:testFont1;font-size:15px;'> ${test[i]} </p>
    
<pstyle='margin-left:3%;color:white;font-family:testFont1;font-size:17px;line-height:5px;'>${'someothertext'}</p>
         
<pstyle='margin-left:3%;color:white;font-family:testFont1;font-size:12px;line-height:10px;'>
${test[i]}</p>
            
<pstyle='margin-left:3%;padding-bottom:8%;color:white;font-family:testFont1;font-size:12px;line-height:-10px;'>${'someothertext'}</p>`;

    listItem.innerHTML = html;
    allresults.appendChild(listItem);
    $(listItem).on('click', testAlert);
  }
}

function testAlert(e){
  let text = $(e.target.parentElement.firstChild).html().trim();
    alert(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="searchResults">        
    <div id="allresults" >              
    </div>        
</div>

<button id=test>click me</button>
```

I want to tap on a `div` tag named `allresults` and that `div` tag is supposed to return me a set value in dataset. In my case, it would be `appleType`.

However I have no idea why I can't just type in any part of the `div` tag named `allresults`. I have to be very specific in tapping on the `appleType` only then it would show me the alert. If I tap on any other place it will alert `undefined`.

So what I want is to be able to tap anywhere to get the alert of `appleType`.

The for loop in my JS is looping through the database and displaying out all values in my HTML page in a `div` tag called `allresults`

My JS file:

```
for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++){
   var listItem = document.createElement('text'),
   html = " res.rows.item(i).appleType + "<br>" + res.rows.item(i).pearType;

   listItem.dataset.appleType = res.rows.item(i).appleType;
   listItem.innerHTML = html;
   allresults.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

My Html File:

```
<div id="searchResults" style="margin-top:40%" >

   <div id="allresults" style="background-image:url(css/images/SidePanel/searchWidgetBG.png);background-size:100%;margin-top:1%">
   </div>
</div>
```

My JS file to call the tapped div:

```
function testAlert(e){
     var appleType = e.target.dataset.appleType;
     alert(appleType);
}

$('#allresults').on('click',  testAlert);
```

Comment: If any error, what type of error does your code produce?

Comment: there is no error. the alert is undefined when i tap on empty spaces or on the pearType.. I have to tap in appleType only then the alert shows me the appleType

Answer (score 0):

Ok with source code, I will edit my answer:

Your problem is that you're lumping all the html into the same entity, and you're assuming you can set a property to that thing you're creating.  The e, or event if you will, doesn't have that property applied to it because its a new instance of event itself.

Try this:

```
$(e.target).get(0).firstChild.data;
```

or a non jquery route doing the same thing:

```
e.target.firstChild.data
```

This will return you the first block only of the element you clicked, and ignore the br tag and the following tag.  I hope this is what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/wfbj0bgs/

Comment: If i use.children() nothing happens any longer :/ let me try to make a js.fiddle

Comment: Ok so you want to be able to click anywhere within the #allresults, but you want any child that has been appended to return?

The reason you're getting undefined is because #allresults doesn't have a e.target.dataset.appleType

Comment: ok i have done a js.fiddle maybe u can tweak what i did so that doesnt matter if i click on the fruit name or the some other text it should alert me the fruit name

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, helped a lot. Let me know if this answers your question with an upvote or not.

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle! I'm almost there! please have a look at my fiddle once more. i added <p> tags so now if i click between two lines it says undefined! how to i treat everything as one item when i click it?

Comment: You added <br><p> at the start.

So you need to traverse through it differently than the method I showed.

Comment: U can remove the br actually I just want to work with p tags but they are naturally block elements so they do have space between them. Can I make put all the p tags in a div tag?

Comment: Updated for you here.  Notice how I am changing the p tag's css value for its margin.  Margin clicks on elements dont propogate upwards.  And p blocks by nature, are given varying margins depending upon the browser used.

https://jsfiddle.net/wfbj0bgs/2/

Comment: I'm also wrapping your html variable in a template string.  Those help a lot if you need to do some markup with a bunch of elements.

Comment: The reason for the trim() call is because when you use a template string, spaces and carriage returns are included.  If you don't wish to trim() this way, use the template string without any spaces like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/wfbj0bgs/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162243/discussion-between-uraforclain-and-simon).